# Ruby undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Why is this not a valid operation?

```
def get_highest_bar()
   #convert string to integer array
   data = @data.split(",")

   return Integer(data.max)
end

 #rounds up to nearest factor of 100
 def round_up(n)
     return 100 if n < 100
     return (n+50)/100*100
 end

@axis_range_prefix = "chxr=" 
@y_axis_index = "1"

#error here:
axis_range = @axis_range_prefix + [@y_axis_index, "0", highest_bar.to_s()].join(",")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need the get_ prefix in your get_highest_bar method. That's a java habit, isn't it? The fact that you called it highest_bar later proves that a good name reflects what the result is, not the action you took to get it.
2. Parens after the method definition are optional and not idiomatic ruby.
3. The `return Integer(data.max)` probably doesn't do what you think. If `@data` contained "1,10,2" the max is 2, because they're being compared as strings.

Rewritten method:

```
def highest_bar
   @data.split(",").map(&:to_i).max
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Java tendencies die hard. Does the `.map(&:to_i)` portion feed every value in the list to the to_i() function? What do the '&' and ':' mean? Sorry I am new to ruby.

Comment: It's shorthand for `.map{|x| x.to_i}`

Comment: When I try to do `@data.split(",").map(&:to_i).max` I receive an error: 'wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)'

Comment: I see, that shortcut only works 1.8.6+ the company I work for only has 1.8.4

Comment: Really? That's pretty ancient. The company had better start thinking about an upgrade plan.

Comment: I'll bring it up to them, I am just interning here for the summer. I didn't think to check the version bc at home I have Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, **highest_bar** is undefined.  You should call **get_highest_bar**().  I.e.

```
 axis_range = @axis_range_prefix + [@y_axis_index, "0", get_highest_bar.to_s()].join(",")
```

Comment: highest_bar is the name of a local variable, which after looking at what I posted i forgot to include. My mistake.